# Strange class member function behaviour

Tags: php, class-members

I have a strange problem with a PHP class. If I do this:

```
$message= new Message();
$message->load(43);
```

it won't work, the script gives no webpage.

But if I do this:

```
$message=new Message();
$message->loadMessageBasics(43);
$message->loadMessageMembers(43);
$message->loadMessageStates(43);
```

then print_r($message) just gives what I expected.

Could someone please enlighten me what I do wrong?

Here's the Message class file.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

    class Message
    {
        public $id;
        public $recipients;
        public $sender;
        public $subject;
        public $body;
        public $creationDate;
        public $msgStates;

        function __construct() {
        }

        public function load($mid){
            $this->loadMessageBasics($mid);
            $this->loadMessageMembers($mid);
            $this->loadMessageStates($mid);

        }

        public function loadMessageBasics($mid){
            try{

                $db=initdb();
                $result=$db->run("SELECT id, feladoid, targy, szovegtorzs, l_idopont FROM messages WHERE id=".$mid);
                foreach($result as $row){
                    extract($row);
                    $this->id=$id;
                    $sender=new User();
                    $sender->load($feladoid);
                    $this->sender=$sender;
                    $this->subject=$targy;
                    $this->body=$szovegtorzs;
                    $this->creationDate=$l_idopont;
                }
                $db=null;

            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo("Hiba: ".$e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public function loadMessageMembers($mid){
            try{
                $db=initdb();
                $result=$db->run("SELECT id, tagkod, tagid, l_idopont, m_idopont FROM members WHERE modulkod=11 AND modulid=".$mid);
                foreach($result as $row){
                    extract($row);
                    $newRecipient= new Member();
                    $newRecipient->id=$id;
                    $newRecipient->tagkod=$tagkod;
                    $newRecipient->tagid=$tagid;
                    $newRecipient->l_idopont=$l_idopont;
                    $newRecipient->m_idopont=$m_idopont;
                    $this->recipients[]=$newRecipient;
                    echo("<PRE>");
                    print_r($newRecipient);
                    echo("</PRE>");
                }
                $db=null;

            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo("Hiba: ".$e->getMessage());
            }


        }
        public function loadMessageStates($mid){
            try{
                $db=initdb();
                $result=$db->run("SELECT id, uzenetid, userid, mappakod, o_idopont, m_idopont FROM msgstates WHERE uzenetid=".$mid);
                foreach($result as $row){
                    extract($row);
                    $newState= new MsgState();
                    $newState->id=$id;
                    $newState->uzenetid=$uzenetid;
                    $newState->userid=$userid;
                    $newState->mappakod=$mappakod;
                    $newState->o_idopont=$o_idopont;
                    $newState->m_idopont=$m_idopont;
                    $this->msgStates[]=$newState;
                }
                $db=null;

            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                echo("Hiba: ".$e->getMessage());
            }


        }

    }
?>
```

UPDATE:

It seems that the problem is with the XAMPP Apache or PHP part. The server Application eventlog says:

```
Napló neve:    Application
Forrás:        Application Error
Dátum:         2013.06.13. 9:03:55
Eseményazonosító:1000
Feladatkategória:(100)
Szint:         Hiba
Kulcsszavak:   Klasszikus
Felhasználó:   n.a.
Számítógép:    SZENTENDRE.iirf.hu
Leírás:
A hibát okozó alkalmazás neve: httpd.exe, verzió: 2.4.3.0, időbélyeg: 0x502f70a3
A hibát okozó modul neve: php5ts.dll, verzió: 5.4.7.0, időbélyeg: 0x505114f8
Kivételkód: 0xc0000005
Hiba pozíciója: 0x0004e399
A hibát okozó folyamat azonosítója: 0x860
A hibát okozó alkalmazás indításának időpontja: 0x01ce680080b003fa
A hibát okozó alkalmazás elérési útja: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe
A hibát okozó modul elérési útja: C:\xampp\php\php5ts.dll
Jelentés azonosítója: 68aa9b7c-d3f7-11e2-a808-00241d779aba
Esemény XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-06-13T07:03:55.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>10202</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>SZENTENDRE.iirf.hu</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>httpd.exe</Data>
    <Data>2.4.3.0</Data>
    <Data>502f70a3</Data>
    <Data>php5ts.dll</Data>
    <Data>5.4.7.0</Data>
    <Data>505114f8</Data>
    <Data>c0000005</Data>
    <Data>0004e399</Data>
    <Data>860</Data>
    <Data>01ce680080b003fa</Data>
    <Data>C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\xampp\php\php5ts.dll</Data>
    <Data>68aa9b7c-d3f7-11e2-a808-00241d779aba</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

(Sorry, it's in Hungarian)

And Apache eventlog says all the time after crashes:

```
[Thu Jun 13 09:03:55.233443 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4252:tid 396] AH00428:     Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Thu Jun 13 09:03:55.826244 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4252:tid 396] AH00455: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 13 09:03:55.826244 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4252:tid 396] AH00456: Server built: Aug 18 2012 12:41:37
[Thu Jun 13 09:03:55.826244 2013] [core:notice] [pid 4252:tid 396] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Jun 13 09:03:55.826244 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4252:tid 396] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2288
[Thu Jun 13 09:03:57.245846 2013] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2288:tid 288] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Anyone has any suggestions what should I do about it?

Comment: "won't work" is not suitable for describing a problem, please be more specific about _what_ is not working.

Comment: Sorry for being lazy :-) What I expect is a print_r() output of the $message object. With using $message->load() there's no output at all, just an Error: 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET) screen in my browser. After using the three separate functions one by one like $message-loadMessageBasics() etc. I can print_r() the object without problems. That's what I meant to say.

Comment: Have you checked the webserver logfiles? Or did you do any debugging on the issue already?
From what I can see, there is no obvious reason for why the single method calls succeed and the "bulk method" does not. So the real reason might be hidden somewhere else in your project. ERR_CONNECTION_RESET has a wide range of possible reasons, you might want to do some internet research for more information about that issue. Sorry that I could not help you that much :(

Comment: Thanks anyway, I will try checking the logfiles.